# What is Best ebook reader for reading mathematics texts?

Tags: ebook-readers, pdf, e-ink, djvu

I want to know what is the best user-friendly ebook reader for reading mathematics text books. It should use e-ink display and should be able to read pdf and djvu files, text, scanned text, images.

Comment: nice comparison: http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/EBook_Reader_Matrix